# Multer and CSRF and <form action="?_method=PUT">

Tags: node.js, express, csrf, multer, cloudinary

So, ive just added multer and cloudinary to my project.
whenever I add something to my db using my form. it gives this error
"ForbiddenError: invalid csrf token"

but i've fixed that by adding `?_csrf=<%= csrfToken %>"` to my action attribute in my form

```
<form action="/admin?_csrf=<%= csrfToken %>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Now, I'm trying to do the same thing for my update route.
and it's giving me the same error from before "ForbiddenError: invalid csrf token"

I've tried doing 
`<form action="/admin/<%= prod._id %>?_method=PUT?_csrf=<%= csrfToken %>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

or this

`<form action="/admin/<%= prod._id %>?_method=PUT?_csrf=<%= csrfToken %>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

or this

`<form action="/admin/<%= prod._id %>?_method=PUT_csrf=<%= csrfToken %>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

or this

`<form action="/admin/<%= prod._id %>?_csrf=<%= csrfToken %>_method=PUT" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

you know... different kind of variations... hoping one would work. hahah

anyways, is what I am doing impossible? that I could have 2 methods in my action attribute?

is there another way i could do this somehow?

Edit.ejs

```
<section class="no-padding-top">
  <div class="container-fuid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="block">
        <div class="title"><strong>Edit Item</strong></div>
          <form action="/admin/<%= prod._id %>?_method=PUT" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
           <div class="form-group row">
              <label class="col-sm-3 form-control-label">Product Name</label>
              <div class="col-sm-9">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="prod[name]" value="<%= prod.name %>" required>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="image" class="col-sm-3 form-control-label">Product Image</label>
              <div class="col-sm-9">
              <input type="file" id="image" name="image" accept="image/*" >
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label class="col-sm-3 form-control-label">Product Price</label>
              <div class="col-sm-3">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="prod[price]" value="<%= prod.price %>" required>
              </div>
              <label class="col-sm-1 form-control-label">Product Quantity</label>
              <div class="col-sm-2">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="prod[quantity]" value="<%= prod.quantity %>" required>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label class="col-sm-3 form-control-label">Product Brand</label>
              <div class="col-sm-3">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="prod[brand]" value="<%= prod.brand %>"  required>
              </div>
              <label class="col-sm-1 form-control-label">Product type</label>
              <div class="col-sm-2">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="prod[type]" placeholder="Types of produces. i.e Wheels, Lights, Steering Wheels..." value="<%= prod.type %>" required>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label class="col-sm-3 form-control-label">Product Description</label>
              <div class="col-sm-9">
              <textarea cols="30" rows="10" class="form-control" name="prod[description]" required> <%= prod.description%> </textarea>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <div class="col-sm-9 ml-auto">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Edit Item</button>
                <a href="/admin" class="btn btn-info ml-3">Cancel</a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="<%= csrfToken %>">
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

multer and cloudinary start

```
var multer = require('multer');
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  filename: function(req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, Date.now() + file.originalname);
  }
});
var imageFilter = function (req, file, cb) {
    // accept image files only
    if (!file.originalname.match(/\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$/i)) {
        return cb(new Error('Only image files are allowed!'), false);
    }
    cb(null, true);
};
var upload = multer({ storage: storage, fileFilter: imageFilter})

var cloudinary = require('cloudinary');
cloudinary.config({ 
  cloud_name: 'pitscaraccessories', 
  api_key: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_KEY, 
  api_secret: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET
});
```

update route

```
router.put("/:id", middleware.isLoggedIn, middleware.isAdmin, upload.single('image'), function(req, res) {
    Product.findById(req.params.id, async function(err, prod) {
        if (err) {
            req.flash("error", err.message);
        } else {
            if (req.file) {
                try {

                    await cloudinary.v2.uploader.destroy(prod.imageId);
                    var result = await cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(req.file.path);
                    prod.image = result.secure_url;
                    prod.imageId = result.public_id;

                } catch (err) {
                    req.flash("error", err.message);
                    return res.redirect("back");
                }
            }

            prod.save();

            req.flash("success", "Updated Successfully");
            res.redirect("/admin");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fixed this by doing this to my code. changed my route from `.put` to `.post`

and manually just updating each input inside.

```
router.post("/:id", middleware.isLoggedIn, middleware.isAdmin, upload.single('image'), function(req, res) {
    Product.findById(req.params.id, async function(err, prod) {
        if (err) {
            req.flash("error", err.message);
        } else {
            if (req.file) {
                try {
                    await cloudinary.v2.uploader.destroy(prod.imageId);
                    var result = await cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(req.file.path);
                    prod.image = result.secure_url;
                    prod.imageId = result.public_id;
                } catch (err) {
                    req.flash("error", err.message);
                    return res.redirect("back");
                }
            }

            prod.name = req.body.name;
            prod.price = req.body.price;
            prod.quantity = req.body.quantity;
            prod.brand = req.body.brand;
            prod.type = req.body.type;
            prod.description = req.body.description;

            prod.save();

            req.flash("success", "Updated Successfully");
            res.redirect("/admin");
        }
    });
});
```

and doing this to my form element

`<form action="/admin/<%= prod._id %>?_csrf=<%= csrfToken %>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, maybe you didn't try enough permutations ;D

This syntax worked for me

```
<form action="/users/<%= user._id %>?_method=PUT&_csrf=<%= csrfToken %>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```